# How do I authenticate a new user table in laravel 10.32.1

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

I'm developing a system that needs to authenticate two users ('user' and 'motoboy'). I was already able to authenticate the user using auth::attempt but when I repeated it to the 'motoboy' it authenticates in the 'user' table.
Basically what I want is an auth::attempt for the 'user' table and another for the 'motoboy' table. Can someone help me?

[My DB:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wagY9.png)

My MotoboyController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Motoboy;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class MotoboyController extends Controller
{
    public function login()
    {
        $css = '/assets/css/users/create.css';
        $title = 'Motoboy - Login';

        return view('motoboys.login', ['css' => $css, 'title' => $title]);
    }

    public function auth(Request $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'email' => ['required', 'email'],
            'password' => ['required'],
        ]);

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();

            return redirect()->intended(route('dashboard'));
        }

        return back()->withErrors([
            'login' => 'Deu ruim!'
        ]);
    }
```

My Model Motoboy

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Motoboy extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'motoboys';
    protected $attributes = ['id_status' => 1];
}
```

My code is authenticating the motoboy with the user table. Do I have to create a new provider? and how do I do this?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: Maybe this will help you: -  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3B0sCRCHOo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel has a concept of authentication guards developed for this use case. It is located in the `auth.php` file in your config folder.

Add a `motor-boy` guard to the guards array

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
    'motor-boy' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'motor-boy',
    ],
    ...
],
```

Add a `motor-boy` guard provider to the provider's array. This ensures that the guard is authenticated against the model specified.

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
    'motor-boy' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Motoboy::class,
    ],
...
],
```

Next is to use auth attempt in your controller like this

```
Auth::guard('motor-boy')->attempt($credentials);
```

Finally, after a successful login, you need to set the default auth guard for the currently logged-in session to moto-boy like this

```
config()->set('auth.defaults.guard', 'motor-boy');
```

This ensures that when you call `Auth::user()` or `auth()->user()`, it'll fetch the authenticated `motor-boy` profile by default(without specifying the guard).

PS: `auth()` is a facade helper for the `Auth` class. You can also read more about custom guards [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication#adding-custom-guards)